# How to ordering or sort array by keys in ascending using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

My problem is that I want to sort array keys by ascending and I am googling last 2 days what I am getting the solution is uksort, ksort but it's not give the exact solution what am I want.I feel great full for helping to solve this issue. My output array is:-

```
Array
(
[2020-06-22,13:00] => Array
(
    [0] => 1663
    [1] => 1664
)

[2020-06-22,14:00] => Array
(
    [0] => 1665
    [1] => 1666
)

[2020-06-24,13:00] => Array
(
    [0] => 1715
)

[2020-06-24,8:30] => Array
(
    [0] => 1714
)

[2020-06-23,13:00] => Array
(
    [0] => 1724
)

[2020-06-23,8:30] => Array
(
    [0] => 1727
)
)
```

and we need array is in:-

```
 Array
(
 [2020-06-22,13:00] => Array
(
    [0] => 1663
    [1] => 1664
)

[2020-06-22,14:00] => Array
(
    [0] => 1665
    [1] => 1666
)

[2020-06-23,8:30] => Array
(
    [0] => 1727
)

[2020-06-23,13:00] => Array
(
    [0] => 1724
)

[2020-06-24,8:30] => Array
(
    [0] => 1714
)

[2020-06-24,13:00] => Array
(
    [0] => 1715
)
)
```

Comment: if you convert h:mm(8:30) to hh:mm(08:30), i think it may work. in that case it compares `8` with `1`(first digits).

Comment: Also you can show your query so we can helps adjust the ordering. in regards to @Ersoy  suggestion.

Comment: @Ersoy  Thank you for your reply but I just want to re-order this array in ascending order of date and time.